# UITableView dynamicCell with UIScrollView multi view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Does anybody on here know a good tutorial for loading `dynamicCell` into a `UITableViewController`, which towards to different `UIScrollView` from each cell(to enable the full photos content to be viewed on the device).

I have been looking at the problem for a while and cant get my head around it! I can get a UITableViewController as a static cell towards to ScrollView, but i cant seem to get dynamicCell towards different `uiscrollview` with `uipagecontroller`! the following to create a model (`Reciepe.h`)

```
@interface Recipe : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; // name of recipe
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile; // image filename of recipe
@end
```

about the main view is named (`ReciepeBookViewController.m`) the ViewDidLoadas the follow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Initialize table data

Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
recipe1.name = @"Egg Benedict";
recipe1.imageFile = @"egg_benedict.jpg";

Recipe *recipe2 = [Recipe new];
recipe2.name = @"Mushroom Risotto";
recipe2.imageFile = @"mushroom_risotto.jpg";

Recipe *recipe3 = [Recipe new];
recipe3.name = @"Full Breakfast";
recipe3.imageFile = @"full_breakfast.jpg";


Recipe *recipe4 = [Recipe new];
recipe4.name = @"Hamburger";
recipe4.imageFile = @"hamburger.jpg";


Recipe *recipe5 = [Recipe new];
recipe5.name = @"Ham and Egg Sandwich";
recipe5.imageFile = @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg";

Recipe *recipe6 = [Recipe new];
recipe6.name = @"Creme Brelee";
recipe6.imageFile = @"creme_brelee.jpg";

Recipe *recipe7 = [Recipe new];
recipe7.name = @"White Chocolate Donut";
recipe7.imageFile = @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg";


Recipe *recipe8 = [Recipe new];
recipe8.name = @"White Chocolate Mocha";
recipe8.imageFile = @"starbucks_coffee.jpg";

Recipe *recipe9 = [Recipe new];
recipe9.name = @"Vegetable Curry";
recipe9.imageFile = @"vegetable_curry.jpg";


Recipe *recipe10 = [Recipe new];
recipe10.name = @"Instant Noodle with Egg";
recipe10.imageFile = @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg";

Recipe *recipe11 = [Recipe new];
recipe11.name = @"Noodle with BBQ Pork";
recipe11.imageFile = @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg";


Recipe *recipe12 = [Recipe new];
recipe12.name = @"Japanese Noodle with Pork";
recipe12.imageFile = @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg";


Recipe *recipe13 = [Recipe new];
recipe13.name = @"Green Tea";
recipe13.imageFile = @"green_tea.jpg";

Recipe *recipe14 = [Recipe new];
recipe14.name = @"Thai Shrimp Cake";
recipe14.imageFile = @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg";

Recipe *recipe15 = [Recipe new];
recipe15.name = @"Angry Birds Cake";
recipe15.imageFile = @"angry_birds_cake.jpg";

Recipe *recipe16 = [Recipe new];
recipe16.name = @"Ham and Cheese Panini";
recipe16.imageFile = @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg";

recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe1, recipe2, recipe3, recipe4, recipe5, recipe6, recipe7, recipe8, recipe9, recipe10, recipe11, recipe12, recipe13, recipe14, recipe15, recipe16, nil];


}
```

I need when user select "Ham and Cheese Panini" go to another viewController with `UIScrollController` with `PageController` with images array, and when user select Angry Birds Cakego to another view with UIScrollController with PageController with another image array and so on for each `Reciepe`.

Can anybody to tell me about the suitable solution or suitable tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to use dynamic cells, I hope it helps !

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

Comment: thanks for your help; but i need for `DetailViewController` another image array; so please if you can provide me a tutorial for that